# Ubuntu 20.04 after setting static IP, apt update and SSL stopped working

Tags: apt, server, 20.04, netplan, static-ip

I ws running mu Ubuntu server 20.04 (command line only) for few weeks with IP 192.168.1.5, unaware that it was dynamic. Today the IP changed to 192.168.1.6. I decided to change it to static with this guide: https://www.linuxtechi.com/assign-static-ip-address-ubuntu-20-04-lts/

I was able to set my `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` to look like this:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      addresses: [192.168.1.5/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [4.2.2.2, 8.8.8.8]
  version: 2
```

After `sudo netplan apply` the IP `192.168.1.5` worked just fine again, however my SSL settings does not work anymore (I was able to set SSL with this guide: https://devanswers.co/install-lets-encrypt-ssl-cert-apache-ubuntu-20-04/).

I tried to renew it with `sudo certbot renew --dry-run`, but it didn't work. I wanted to restart it completly with `sudo apt update && sudo apt install certbot python-certbot-apache` and I noticed, that I can not use now `sudo apt update` at all. It returns `[0%] Working` for some time and than throws `Temporary translation error` (I'm not sure if this error message is stated like this in english since I'm getting it in my language).

I'm pretty sure that I should do something more after changing the `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` file, but I have no idea what am I missing?

Comment: Have you rebooted since you did `sudo netplan apply`?

Comment: Yes, I did, it does not help. Is there any additional info that I should provide to the question that might help?

Comment: Can you login to your router? Perhaps it already assigned .5 to another device on your network.

Comment: user535733 has a good point... are you sure that .5 isn't already used? For testing, change your .yaml back to dhcp4: true (dynamic addressing), and see if things start to work again. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I can confirm that 192.168.1.5 is assigned to the correct device. It does work, only SSL seems to be "disconnected", and I can not do `apt upgrade`.

Comment: @heynnema I set `dhcp4: true` when server had IP `192.168.1.5`. After `sudo netplan apply`, without need to restart everything goes back to normal - work as intended, both SSL and apt update. Yet now it is dynamic again, and I'd like to leave it be static.

Comment: In `terminal` type `ping 192.168.1.5`. Report back.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema I use putty to connect with the server from my windows PC and it does connect in both cases: static and dynamic IP. I tried to ping it and it does work correctly, on both settings.

Comment: What is the current server IP?

Comment: @heynnema It is 192.168.1.5 all the time. Only change that I make is that I replace `      addresses: [192.168.1.5/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [4.2.2.2, 8.8.8.8]` with `dhcp4: true` back and forth.

Comment: OK, let me confirm... if you set up your .yaml to use dynamic addressing, it picks up the .5 address and SSL and apt update both work, correct? And if you change to use static IP addressing to .5, SSL and apt update both fail, correct?

Comment: @heynnema Yes, this is correct. Perhaps there is something wrong in my static address syntax? It does look exactly like quoted in my original question post. I'm unable to find any error, and in fact it does kinda-work...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113379/discussion-between-heynnema-and-zorann).

Answer (score 0):

A tip: to prevent something non reversible in the config (like, you are SSH-ing to a dedicated (e.g. Hetzner) Server and apply a non working config and absolutely loose connection to your server) you should type

`sudo netplan try` instead of `sudo netplan apply`

to let the system test the config. If errors occur, the config does not apply, the system warns and show you the mistakes in the .yaml file, so you can change settings again. If no error occur, there will be a 2-minute timer, which says "Press Enter to apply the settings" or you wait this few minutes to revert your changes (does not apply).

Hope this helps someone.